# Function allows word but not Phrase c++

Tags: c++, string, function

I have a function that allows a user to input a word or phrase then display it on a menu but for some reason it will display a word but not a phrase, system crashes when I use more than one word

snippet of my function code:

```
string GetWord(void){
    string localString = "";
    cout<< "please enter a new word or phrase: ";
    cin >> localString;
    return localString;
}
```

does anyone know what I have done wrong ? the menu will display a single word but not double.

Answer (score 0):

The input operator `>>` on `std::cin` stops reading at the first space and so just reads one word. This is the defined behavior.

I assume you would like to read until the user presses enter. You want to read a line. You can use `std::getline()` to achieve this:

```
std::string GetWordOrPhrase() {
    std::string localString;
    std::cout << "please enter a new word or phrase: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, localString);
    return localString;
}
```

BTW: Always use the `std::` namespace explicitly in your code. Do not use `using namespace std` just to spare a few characters. (Code is not (only) about making it work with some compiler, but also a communication means between software developers.)

Comment: Hello, I attempted to use your method but it wouldn't allow me to use the function, just went back into the menu option. I then added a void parameter and the cin >> local string above the getline(), but this time it would only show the second word in menu.